# What is better oil for oiling fans: grapeseed or refined?

Tags: fan, oil

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use oil from kitchen for oiling my fans](https://superuser.com/questions/366573/can-i-use-oil-from-kitchen-for-oiling-my-fans)

I want to oil my CPU fan, maybe case fan too (in future). But I have found only mineral oil in my home. I have grapeseed and refined oil. Which should I use for oiling ventilators?

Comment: I think you would want to use something that doesn't attract dust, and most oils do. Oils are sticky...

Comment: @user859955 No, it's now how it works ;)

Comment: Well that sent me rushing to Google :-) It seems the consensus is mineral oil, Vaseline being very good but takes a long while to work in. General view also is don't use WD40 or Graphite based products.

Comment: I would replace the noisy fans. Google "self-stabilizing oil-pressure bearing" .

Comment: @Aki Their not so noisy, I just want to oile them for very quiet workspace.

Comment: I would simply replace the fans (or lower their speed) as well.  I realize that there is a good selection of non-conductive oils available, but I don't like to lubricate anything in a PC if at all possible - it invariably ends up somewhere it shouldn't in the long run.  I certainly wouldn't use ANYTHING other than mineral oil.

Comment: And yes, this is a duplicate.  How did you not see the one of only TWO other questions tagged 'oil'?

Comment: @Shinrai, Roberts asked the other question too.

Comment: Roberts, rather than asking posting a second question that is nearly identical to your first, add details to the first question asking for the additional information.

Comment: @music2myear - Doh.  That makes it even worse, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fans are FRU's.  Do not "oil" them.  REPLACE them.  Even if you get the crazy mamajama ultra quiets yer looking at a whopping 10 to 15 bucks a fan.  Maybe 30 for a decent CPU cooler.

Comment: Your price estimates are too low (there are plenty of really top-tier fans that are $30+ apiece as of this writing even for case fans), but your logic is still sound.  You don't oil fans. >.<

Comment: Um... I am not sure where you are or are looking for your equipment my friend, but looking at Tigerdirect and searching say, all 80mm case fans, the HIGHEST priced one I can locate is 14.99.  Even bumping up to 120mm the highest I can find is 19.99

Can you throw me a link to see what Fan TREASURES you must be seeing in the 30 dollar range??  LOL  CPU fan/Cooler, sure but Case Fans??

Comment: Those numbers are good for 80mm fans, but why are you buying 80mm fans if you want quiet ones? ;)  Examples - all the larger Noiseblocker NB series fans, Noctua NF series fans, pretty much anything good that's 120mm+.  (I'm also factoring in shipping costs.)  Doesn't really matter though, because you're right either way.

Comment: I still aim to peep those brands.  Maybe I am missing out cuz I have never met a single fan that was "quiet enough".  LOL

Comment: That is true but what is even worse using mineral oils for lubrication is a big no go. They attract dust, clump at low temperatures and dissolve in higher temperatures. This would just cause the fan to work for a while and then the OP would need to replace it because it will get ruined.